# ASP.NET MVC 3: why does it think my class is a complex type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Building my project using Code First EF.

I have a `User` class that has, as one of its properties, `List<FriendGroup>` (where a `FriendGroup` is basically just a collection of `User`s, kind of like 'Circles' in Google+).  `FriendGroup` is defined in a different file as a POCO and... here's the thing... I never said anywhere that it is a `ComplexType`.

But when I try to run my application I get the exception,

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'FriendGroup' has already been configured as an entity type. It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type.
```

I would be grateful for any insight anyone might be able to offer on why ASP.NET decided my class is a `ComplexType`.  Thanks in advance!

ETA: relevant bits from my model:

```
namespace Clade.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int userID { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        public Profile profile { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<FriendGroup> friendGroups { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<AchievementEarned> achievementsEarned { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Clade.Models
{
    public class FriendGroup
    {
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int friendGroupID { get; private set; }
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int userID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string friendGroupName { get; set; }
        public Privacy defaultPrivacy { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public List<User> usersInFG { get; set; }

        public void UpdateMe(FriendGroup editedFG)
        {
            friendGroupName = editedFG.friendGroupName;
            defaultPrivacy = editedFG.defaultPrivacy;
            usersInFG = editedFG.usersInFG;
        }
    }
}
```

There's also EF code, repositories, etc. but none of them know anything about the inner workings of any POCO.  The only thing I see here that *may* be problematic is that `User` has a `List<FriendGroup>` and `FriendGroup` has a `List<User>`.  But nothing has ever existed that annotated `FriendGroup` as a `ComplexType`.

ETA (2):  `Profile` is also just a POCO:

```
namespace Clade.Models
{
    public class Profile
    {
        [Key]
        public int profileID { get; private set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
        public DiscussionGroup dg { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public Privacy locationPrivacy { get; set; }
        public string aboutMe { get; set; }
        public Privacy aboutMePrivacy { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

`User` does have `List`s of a couple of `ComplexType`-annotated objects, but EF did not complain about those.

```
namespace Clade.Models
{
    [ComplexType]
    public class AchievementEarned
    {
        public Achievement achievement { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public DateTime dateEarned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ETA (3): Here's the method in `UserRepository` where the error occurs.  It happens on the line which starts with `var results`.

```
    public bool Add(User newUser)
    {
        bool rv = false;

        //check to make sure no one else has the same username first
        var results = from user in Users
                      where user.userName.Equals(newUser.userName)
                      select user;
        if (results.Count() == 0)
        {
            this.context.Users.Add(newUser);
            this.Commit();
            rv = true;
        }

        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: You should provide your model, necessary bits (that compile), scaled-down version. It's probably related to how you're setting up the model, fluent, annotations etc.

Comment: Ok, I've updated with bits from my POCO declarations along with all relevant annotations.  Not using Fluent, so nothing to add there.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the Privacy class code? What version of EF do you use?

Comment: EF 4.3.1 (just installed it a couple of days ago).  `Privacy` is an enum: `public enum Privacy { Public, AllUsers, AllFriends, Custom, Private };`

Comment: You have many problems in there - you have to set up relations properly (and from fluent) - 1-to-1 for user/profile (as I see), and two different relations for user/group + you cannot have navigation properties within complex types. Plus enums mentioned...

Comment: I separated `Profile` from `User` because other entities such as `DiscussionGroup` (which is different from `FriendGroup`) can have a `Profile` too.  The `User`s in the `List` `FriendGroup.usersInFG` will all be different from the `User` who owns it, but I can change those to ints if really necessary too.  I've made sure that every `ComplexType` in the project is made up of primitive types - now to see if it runs.

Comment: Thank you NSGaga, I was able to get past that issue (and on to at least different errors such as "Invalid object name: 'dbo.Users'")

Comment: @SabrinaS you need to 'reference' me (as @NSGaga) so I'd get notified :). This can be worked out nicely (no ints necessary, you should use 'navigation properties'), I can post a full answer with all the details, just confirm the 'relations', add some details if you have (more like a diagram of relations is what's essential). There are many details left (each thing you have left, relation is special case).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:
Use int property instead of Enum
or try to update to EF 5 beta 2 with 
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre 
wich much better supports enums

Comment: Yeah, researching this more, I see that EF does not support enums.  I wouldn't have thought that would be the problem since it was complaining about another class entirely.  Rather than switch to a beta, I think I'll just convert my enums to classes, that way I'll get to have string values too.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, after completely converting `Privacy` to a class, I am still getting the error.  I'll try commenting out every occurrence of it anyway and I guess I'll go ahead and switch to EF 5 beta...

Comment: This error makes no sense whatsoever.  Even when I remove all reference to `FriendGroup` in `User` I **still** get this error.